# Flutter/Dart - Add a torrent using the real-debrid api - invalid torrent error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add a torrent to the real-debrid api using flutter/dart. My function downloads the torrent file, then tries to send it to the api. I am getting error 30 - Invalid torrent file. But if I get the torrent file my app downloads and upload it to the real-debrid website, it works fine - so I'm assuming the torrent file is fine.

I've tried using Dio / Http packages, and checked everything I can think of. Any help would be much appreciated! The real-debrid api documentation says to use a PUT: https://api.real-debrid.com

My function:

```
Future<String> addTorrent(String torrentFileUrl) async {
    // Download the .torrent file
    final responseTorrent = await http.get(Uri.parse(torrentFileUrl));
    final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final filePath = '${directory.path}/file.torrent';
    final file = File(filePath);
    await file.writeAsBytes(responseTorrent.bodyBytes);

    // Upload the .torrent file to Real-Debrid
    var dio = Dio();
    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'files': await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename: 'file.torrent', contentType: MediaType('application', 'x-bittorrent')),
    });

    var response = await dio.put(
      'https://api.real-debrid.com/rest/1.0/torrents/addTorrent',
      data: formData,
      options: Options(
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
        },
      ),
    );

    print('Response status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Response body: ${response.data}');

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response.data['id'];
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to add torrent to Real-Debrid');
    }
  }
```